# Maven distributionManagement or Server (User and Password) as parameter

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a remote repository using Nexus.

These Repositories asks for login, I would prefer to expose these repositories with login.

This is my settings.xml

```
<settings>

<servers>
    <server>
        <id>dev-repo</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>

</settings>
```

And the developers are using a pom.xml with:

```
<distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>dev-repo</id>
                <url>http://ip:port/nexus/content/repositories/dev-repo/</url>                          
            </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

With that configuration everything is OK, but I prefer they have to pass the login in the mvn command or the command ask with a prompt the login instead hard code the login in settings.xml

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's quite easy: The `settings.xml` file allows variables. Replace `user` and `password` by named variables:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>dev-repo</id>
        <username>${user}</username>
        <password>${password}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

And then, provide explicit values when invoking to Maven:

```
mvn -Duser=... -Dpassword=... install
```

Comment: Thanks. I thougt that I wasn't able to do that.